# Is the directorysearcher object capped at 5000 even if pagesize is set to greater

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, active-directory

Is the directorysearcher findall results method capped at 5000 results even if pagesize is set to greater.
It really seems to be, because no matter what I get exactly 5000 results.
This is C#

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, it's a server-side setting which limits the maximum number of entries returned in a single search. Default is 1'000.

Secondly, if you really need to enumerate more than this limit of 1'000 entries, you should look into **paged searches**. Quite simply, set the `DirectorySearcher.PageSize` entry to a value (less than that system limit), e.g. 500, and you'll get your results in pages of 500 entries.

There's no limit on how many entries you'll get in total - you can simply enumerate the `DirectorySearcher.FindAll()` collection and you should be able to handle any number of entries that way. The AD server will just simply batch up your results in pages of 500 - once you've enumerated one page, the next one will be delivered.

Marc

Comment: Trying to find the name of the server-side setting you mentioned which sets a maximum limit on queries. I know I've seen it before but cannot seem to find the documentation on it now. Any chance you remember?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
        mySearcher.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue;
        mySearcher.PageSize = int.MaxValue;
```

Does it still limit to 5k?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Active Directory or your LDAP is capping the query results.

We have a maximum of 1000 elements defined.