# C# Active Directory query results limit

Tags: c#, active-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the directorysearcher object capped at 5000 even if pagesize is set to greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508150/is-the-directorysearcher-object-capped-at-5000-even-if-pagesize-is-set-to-greater)

I'm running a query on a container to determine how many objects it contains:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Users,DC=XXX,DC=YYY");
string filter = "(objectClass=Person)";
string[] properties = { "distinguishedName" };
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry, filter, properties, SearchScope.Subtree);
var results = search.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
    Console.WriteLine(result.Path);
}
Console.WriteLine(results.Count);
entry.Close();
```

However the query always returns at most 2000 objects, even if I explicitly set a different size limit:

```
search.SizeLimit = 10000; // useless
```

How can I get all the results from the query?

Comment: Or see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508150/is-the-directorysearcher-object-capped-at-5000-even-if-pagesize-is-set-to-greater