# Search Active Directory without using LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using C# in VS2008 in a WinXP/Win7/WinServer2003 environment.

Is there a way to search the active directory without involving LDAP?

I have users created in Active Directory but when I search using this

```
        DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(
            new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=kmmnet,DC=com"),
            "(objectClass=user)",
            new string[] { "sAMAccountName", "displayname", "givenname", "sn" });
        foreach (SearchResult s in dirSearcher.FindAll())
        {
            System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection p = s.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties;
        }
```

it cannot find some of the users.

thanks
Shawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try bumping the PageSize attribute up from its default of zero:

```
dirSearcher.PageSize = 9000;
```

Any non-zero value for PageSize will cause paging to occur, so that you will receive all results (in batches equal to the PageSize).

You can also try filtering the search more (e.g., exclude inactive users, etc.).

And, there is [an upper limit on the number of results which a directory server will return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508150/is-the-directorysearcher-object-capped-at-5000-even-if-pagesize-is-set-to-greate) in response to an LDAP query. This limit is controlled and set by an administrator on the domain. I believe the default is 1000.